# PHPExcel - Problema con gran cantidad de datos

Tags: php, phpexcel

Sucede que utilizo esta librería para crear reportes en Excel con un aplicativo básico web en PHP que realiza una consulta en MySQL y son los datos que irán a este documento.

Cuando realizo consultas pequeñas (hablo de 150 o 1000 registros) no tiene problema alguno, lo arroja hasta en 1 minuto sin ningún problema. Pero con esta consulta que me trae al rededor de 15 columnas y con una cantidad de 57 hasta 100 mil resultados no me funciona y termina cayendo el aplicativo PHP (el aplicativo está en mi equipo local).

Quisiera saber si dicho PHPExcel trae algún límite de filas y columnas puesto que es la explicación que hasta ahora estoy contemplando.

Cabe aclarar que ya revise el código PHP por si quizá está realizando bucles infinitos, en MySQL revisé la consulta por si estaba haciendo algo indebido y no, trae perfectamente los registros en menos de 1 o 2 minutos y también ya utilicé esta línea de código. **SOLO EN LA CONSULTA MÁS GRANDE QUE ES LA QUE ARROJA MÁS DE 50 MIL FILAS**.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '4000M');
```

Y, como ven, estoy hasta dando un límite muy grande de memoria. También modifiqué el archivo `php.ini` buscando el tiempo máximo de ejecución y lo aumenté considerablemente también.

No sé que más pueda estar afectando el PHPExcel, no sé si sea que tenga un cierto límite o quizá probablemente yo tenga alguna cosilla en mi código, cosa que no sé, pueda ser, pero como dije anteriormente, ya lo verifiqué hasta el cansancio (de igual manera si quieren que agregué el código que estoy utilizando no tendré problema alguno en editar aquí y agregar el código).

Comment: Yo terminé haciendo un desarrollo propio, todas las bibliotecas de funciones que probé (php y java) terminaban consumiendo enormes cantidades de memoria. Si eres capaz de lidiar con XML puedes hacer como hice yo, lo único especial que debes saber es que las cadenas de caracteres no se almacenan en el xml, si no que se genera una lista de cadenas y en el xml de la hoja de cálculo se pone el índice a ella. Ahh, y me olvidaba que, en realidad, un archivo xlsx es un zip con archivos xml en su interior. Si te animas a hacer tu propia implementación te puedo ayudar con el formato interno.

Comment: Siendo sincero..apenas estoy tomando experiencia en programación y en lo que me hablas no tengo un conocimiento aun...pero pues..eso no significa que no quiera aprender jaja. De verdad si puedo llegar a esa solución que me dices seria algo espectacular! tomando en cuenta que es algo que haré continuamente acá en la empresa donde estoy.

Comment: Ahora no puedo mostrarte el código porque estoy en una reunión familiar, pero si no te responden con otra proposición esta noche te pongo un ejemplo básico.

Comment: Vale, muchísimas gracias. @OscarGarcia

Comment: 50,000 filas, de verdad alguien necesita exportar esa información a excel? mira, yo lo veo poco probable que a alguien le sea util esa información, quizá sea mejor crear un reporte de resumen con php directamente.

Comment: @Aquiles Perez Sí, lo sé, suena muy poco probable que alguien necesite esa gran cantidad..pero, es un reporte que se hace anual y necesitan la información de todas sus ventas consolidadas de un año o, inclusive, año vs año. Y sí, también el aplicativo genera un resumen más corto sobre que proveedor o que línea en específico desean ver dichas ventas. Aún así teniendo dicha función..necesitan es ese informe completo y esta consulta arroja una cantidad de datos abismal (Puesto que hay ventas cada día).

Comment: Por ejemplo en mi empresa, hay un erp en el cual nadie pensó en el rendimiento y hacen consultas absurdas como select * from y a la hora de buscar un cheque debes esperar hasta 4 minutos, el rendimiento en la web es muy importante asi que como solucion te recomiendo la paginacion y los filtros, puede ser que al usuario solo le interese la informacion del año 2017 por ejemplo y eso acortaria tus registros, aun asi si los necesitas todos pues si es un problema. de lo que no estoy seguro es de que al final utilizen esa informacion, para tomar alguna decision.

Comment: Sí, lo sé. En sí el aplicativo web tiene filtros para las líneas, el proveedor, el año (Si desean reportes por mes,bimestral, trimestral, semestral o ya de año), y comparativos de año vs año (mes vs mes, bimestre vs bimestre, semestre vs semestre, año vs año). En sí las consultas que tienen filtros específicos (Hablo de líneas y proveedores) así las arrojen semestrales como MÁXIMO tarda 2 o 3 minutos generando el reporte..el problema es cuando desean las consultas sin filtro de línea..y te hablo que son más de 100 líneas que se mueven y cada día se realizan ventas..es un problema muy grande.

Comment: Yo me uno al criterio de los anteriores, me imagino que quieran el excel para mantenerlo como prueba de auditorías o algo por el estilo. De todos modos, para optimizar un poco PHPExcel admite mostrar el resultado directo de una consulta sin tener que volver a iterar por el resultset.

Comment: te sugiero leer testo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895230/why-phpexcel-does-not-allow-to-write-more-than-5000-rows

Comment: Siento haber dejado abandonada esta respuesta. Tal y como te comenté inicialmente terminamos haciendo nuestra propia implementación, aunque ahora que he visto relanzada por la comunidad tu otra pregunta, aprovecho para actualizar ésta.

Comment: La otra pregunta es: [PHPExcel genera error "Allowed memory size of ... bytes exhausted"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/69486/phpexcel-genera-error-allowed-memory-size-of-bytes-exhausted).

Answer (score 2):

### Descripción del problema

Tanto PHPExcel como PhpSpreadsheet tienen un problema de escalabilidad muy serio. En ambos cada celda con datos de tu hoja de cálculo ocupa en media 1 KiB. Además, tal y como veremos a continuación en las gráficas, el tiempo para procesar el trabajo de crear la hoja, poblarla de datos y guardarla aumenta exponencialmente en los dos.

Por poner un ejemplo, una hoja de cálculo con 200.000 filas y 15 columnas ocuparía en memoria `200.000 · 15 · 1 KiB = 3.000.000 KiB`, unos **2.86 GiB** de RAM.

Esto puede leerse en la documentación del [uso de memoria de PhpSpreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/memory_saving/) (sucesor de PHPExcel):

> PhpSpreadsheet uses an average of about 1k per cell in your worksheets, so large workbooks can quickly use up available memory. Cell caching provides a mechanism that allows PhpSpreadsheet to maintain the cell objects in a smaller size of memory, or off-memory (eg: on disk, in APCu, memcache or redis). This allows you to reduce the memory usage for large workbooks, although at a cost of speed to access cell data.

En castellano:

> PhpSpreadsheet (y PHPExcel) usan una media de 1k por celda de tus hojas, por lo que las hojas de cálculo grandes pueden usar rápidamente toda la memoria disponible. La caché de celdas provee a PhpSpreadsheet un mecanismo que le permite mantener los objetos de celda en un tamaño más pequeño de memoria, o fuera de memoria (pe: en disco, en APCu, memcache o redis). Esto te permite reducir el uso de memoria para hojas de cálculo grandes, This allows you to reduce the memory usage for large workbooks, aunque a costa de velocidad de acceso a los datos de las celdas.

Tal y como veremos a continuación en las gráficas, esa media de uso de memoria es muy acertada, pero el efecto de usar una caché apenas es apreciable, al menos en PHPExcel.

### Solución propuesta

La única solución que te puede funcionar a largo plazo es migrar tu código a una biblioteca de funciones que no tenga problemas de escalabilidad como es [Spout](https://github.com/box/spout).

El uso de memoria es prácticamente constante y lo único que aumenta de manera prácticamente lineal es el tiempo que se tarda en generar, poblar la hoja de datos y guardar el archivo.

Medidas como aumentar el límite máximo de memoria que pueda usar PHP con `memory_limit` sólo te permite parchear el problema a costa de aumentar el tiempo de trabajo y consumir los recursos de tu servidor.

### Medidas de rendimiento

A continuación muestro el código de ejemplo utilizado para generar un archivo Excel con una única columna que contiene el texto "Fila: " indicando por parámetro el número de filas que deben generarse:

#### PHPExcel

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$nFilas = isset($_SERVER['argv'][1])?intval($_SERVER['argv'][1]):0;
ini_set('memory_limit', '2G');

$inicio = microtime(true);
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

/* Cambiar este comentario dependiendo de la prueba a realizar: */
/*$cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_to_phpTemp;
$cacheSettings = array( 
  //'memoryCacheSize' => '20'
  'memoryCacheSize' => '8MB'
);
PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod);*/

$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
for ($fila = 1; $fila <= $nFilas; $fila++) {
  $objWorksheet->setCellValueExplicit(
    'A' . $fila,
    "Fila: $fila",
    PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING
  );
}

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, "Excel2007");
$objWriter->save("resultado.xlsx");

echo implode(' ', [
  $nFilas,
  memory_get_peak_usage(true),
  microtime(true) - $inicio,
  filesize("resultado.xlsx")
]), PHP_EOL;
```

#### PhpSpreadsheet

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$nFilas = isset($_SERVER['argv'][1])?intval($_SERVER['argv'][1]):0;
ini_set('memory_limit', '2G');

$inicio = microtime(true);
$objPHPExcel = new PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet();

$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
for ($fila = 1; $fila <= $nFilas; $fila++) {
  $objWorksheet->setCellValueExplicit(
    'A' . $fila,
    "Fila: $fila",
    PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataType::TYPE_STRING
  );
}

$objWriter = new PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save("resultado.xlsx");

echo implode(' ', [
  $nFilas,
  memory_get_peak_usage(true),
  microtime(true) - $inicio,
  filesize("resultado.xlsx")
]), PHP_EOL;
```

#### Spout

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$nFilas = isset($_SERVER['argv'][1])?intval($_SERVER['argv'][1]):0;
ini_set('memory_limit', '2G');

$inicio = microtime(true);
$writer = Box\Spout\Writer\WriterFactory::create(Box\Spout\Common\Type::XLSX);
$writer->setShouldCreateNewSheetsAutomatically(false);
/* Cambiar para la prueba de datos inline o shared */
//$writer->setShouldUseInlineStrings(true);
$writer->setShouldUseInlineStrings(false);
$writer->openToFile("resultado.xlsx");

for ($fila = 1; $fila <= $nFilas; $fila++) {
  $writer->addRow(["Fila: $fila"]);
}

$writer->close();

echo implode(' ', [
  $nFilas,
  memory_get_peak_usage(true),
  microtime(true) - $inicio,
  filesize("resultado.xlsx")
]), PHP_EOL;
```

### Resultados y conclusiones

#### Uso de memoria:

[image: Uso de memoria de las pruebas]

Mientras que PHPExcel y PhpSpreadsheet tienen un uso lineal de memoria (en media 1 KiB por celda de datos), Spout mantiene un consumo de memoria constante de 2 MiB en total.

#### Tiempo de ejecución:

[image: Tiempo de ejecución]

PHPExcel y PhpSpreadsheet aumentan de manera exponencial el tiempo total de ejecución, mientras que Spout aumenta de manera prácticamente lineal.

#### Tamaño del archivo generado:

[image: Tamaño del archivo generado]

En este apartado todos los resultados son muy parecidos (con diferencias de pocos bytes), reduciéndose el tamaño del archivo en caso de usar datos en línea (inline) ya que no se genera un archivo de diccionario separado, si no que los datos se guardan directamente en el XML de las celdas (al igual que ocurre con los datos numéricos).

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar usando BoxSpout (https://github.com/box/spout):

> Es una librería para leer y crear archivos XLSX y CSV, en una forma
>   rápida y escalable. Contrario de lo que otros lectores o escritores,
>   es capaz de procesar archivos grandes mientras mantiene un uso de
>   memoria muy bajo (menos de 10MB). Aquí hay unos números con respecto
>   al rendimiento de Spout.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]